# How do I handle SlowBuffer in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, node-ffi

Now I'm developing a usb-serial application with its dll in Node.js.
This dll returns INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, if it fails to open com port. So I want to handle the ret value in Node.js. In this case, How do I handle below  ?

I'm not sure how do I compare the ret value and SlowBuffer.

**DLL**

```
#define INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE ((HANDLE)(LONG_PTR)-1
typedef HANDLE  (*OPEN)(int);
__declspec(dllexport) HANDLE opencom(int ncom)
```

**Node.js with node-ffi**

```
var ffi = require('ffi');
var lib = ffi.Library('serialmw.dll', {
  'opencom' : ['pointer', ['int']]
});
var hcom = null;
hcom = lib.opencom(1);
console.log(hcom); // <SlowBuffer@0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF >
```

Answer (score 0):

A `SlowBuffer` is just a [`Buffer`](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/buffer.html) which is just a bunch of raw binary bytes. If you want to compare two Buffers byte-for-byte, you will have to use a for-loop or something like the [`buffertools`](https://github.com/bnoordhuis/node-buffertools)' `compare()` with both Buffers.